# odoo 10 : create order from custom module

Tags: odoo-10, inventory

I have a new model in a custom module .
in this module i want to do a backorder on a order (1 product with 2 of quantity)
I want to do this backorder when a field is changed on a form

When i do that i have this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 642, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 684, in
> dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 334, in
> _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in
> wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 327, in
> checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 942, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 507, in
> response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py",
> line 895, in call_kw
> return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py",
> line 887, in _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
> return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in
> call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5535, in
> onchange
> value = record[name]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5269, in
> **getitem**
> return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 930, in
> **get**
> value = record._cache[self]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5620, in
> **getitem**
> value = self._recs.env.cache[field][self._recs.id] KeyError: <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f312b74d150>

Here is my model :

```
class PickingProcess(models.Model):
    _inherit = "mail.thread"
    _name = 'picking.process'
    _description = "picking process ecoparc"

    input_action = fields.Char("Action" ,store=True)
    @api.one
    @api.depends('input_action')
    def _compute_imput_action2(self):
        ctx = dict(self._context or {})
        _logger.error(ctx)
        pic =  self.env['stock.picking'].browse(4910)
        for pack in pic.pack_operation_ids:
            pack.qty_done = 1
    
        backOrderModel = self.env['stock.backorder.confirmation']
        backorderObj = backOrderModel.create(
            {'pick_id': 4910})
        backorderObj._process(cancel_backorder=False) 
        return
```

Do you have an idea why i have this error and how to fix it please?

Thanks a lot
Thomas

Comment: You going in the wrong way. why you create the TransientModel data for backorder?

Comment: hum i foud this on other model in other module infact :(
Do you know the way to do that correctly?

Comment: The backorder flow in odoo it creates the new picking +  new move and move_line link to that picking. So you have to customize it in this way. Like 10 qty order but you delivered 8 than for 2 qty odoo will prepare the new picking with 2 qty.For reference you can take the idea with default odoo process and check the method on backorder popup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. i m still a newbie in odoo .... i ll check it right now

Comment: I try to do just  

 @api.one
    @api.depends('input_action')
    def _compute_imput_action2(self):
        ctx = dict(self._context or {})
        _logger.error(ctx)

        pic =  self.env['stock.picking'].browse(4910)
        for pack in pic.pack_operation_ids:
            pack.qty_done = 1
        pic.do_transfer()


So i remove the call to the transientModel . I have still the same error on the cache id 
KeyError: <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f6bafe2b310>

So before to do the backorder i need to find why i have this error . An other idea?

Comment: The issue is made when do_transfer is finish . as if odoo can't find the picking just validate .

Comment: i call this method by the @api.depends of a form, is it possible it s due by that?